# Force validation/update event without leaving ComboBox control

Tags: vba, forms, validation, events, triggers

On Forms where I have multiple input fields Tab/Enter goes to the next field and that triggers the validation/update process nicely.
However on one of my multipages I have 1 single ComboBox 
I have set it to accept only elements from the list.
The thing is that the user will only get an error popup for wrong values when trying to move to another page, **because hitting Enter/Tab does not trigger validation if there are no other controls to jump on**.

**What command can I put in a `_KeyPress` or `_KeyDown` event that will trigger the validation/update of the ComboBox?**
I expect something like `me.validate` or `me.update` to exist.

Comment: `Me.Repaint` or `Me.Refresh`?

Comment: @Vityata Nah, unfortunately Me.Refresh does not exist in Excel, just in Access I think. Tried with Repaint, but that only repaints the form visually, the Update event is not triggered for the Control.  Any other guesses?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have figured it out finally!
Found my inspiration here: [forum link](https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/49317-combobox-validation-only-listed-items-can-be-chosen-used) 
Maybe there is a more direct approach.. feel free to provide if you know one.
This also handles the main validation, so Better **turn off "MatchRequired"** option!

```
Private Sub MyControl_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    Select Case KeyCode
        Case 9, 13
            If MyControl = vbNullString Then Exit Sub
            If MyControl.ListIndex < 0 Then
                MsgBox "Choose from list"
                MyControl = vbNullString
                Exit Sub
            End If
    End Select
End Sub
```

Cheers!